# How to click on curve and highlight it in a pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

My whole code is based on PyQt5.

I have a table where the user can select data, this data gets then plotted on a graph.
The graph was created like this:

````
```
graph_sheet = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
layout_graph = graph_sheet.addLayout()
plot = pg.PlotItem()
layout_graph.addItem(plot)
line_item = plot.plot(graph_data[x_col], graph_data[y_col], pen=color, name=curve_name)
```
````

In this graph I wanna be able to click on a curve (the user can plot more than one curve on a graph), then it gets highlighted and afterwards I should be able to move it with two sliders horizontally and vertically, that's why I wanna be able to select it with a mouse click.

This line I added after I created line_item:
line_item.sigClicked.connect(lambda c: self.__handle_curve_click(c))

In 'self.__handle_curve_click' I just added a print statement to see if something is happening when clicking a curve. (nothing is happening)

I found several posts where the answer was QGraphicsScene.sigMouseClicked but most of them just wanted to know how to display a certain point on the graph when you click on it. It's also not highlighting the curve. I'm not really sure where to start and how to solve that.

I'm happy with just a description of how to tackle the problem, grateful for any answer :)

EDIT: Found it out myself.

just had to make the lines thicker with .mkPen

```
def handle_curve_click(self, curve):
    print(f"Curve clicked: {curve}")  # for testing
    self.selected_curve = curve

    # Modify the pen properties of the selected curve
    for graphtype, data in self.selectedGraphs.items():
        for line_item, inst in data[1:]:
            if line_item == curve:
                pen = line_item.opts['pen']
                pen = pg.mkPen(pen)
                selected_pen = pg.mkPen(color=pen.color(), width=2)  
                line_item.setPen(selected_pen)
            else:
                line_item.setPen(self.default_pen(line_item))

@staticmethod
def default_pen(line_item):
    pen = line_item.opts['pen']
    pen = pg.mkPen(pen)
    default_pen = pg.mkPen(color=pen.color(), width=1)
    return default_pen
```

I made the curves clickable by adding the line "line_item.setCurveClickable(True)" after I created the PlotDataItem.
Then I connected it with curve.sigClicked.connect(lambda x: self.handle_curve_click(x))

In the next step I created the method handle_curve_click to store the selected line and to tell the program what to do when the line was clicked. In my case, I just make the line thicker by looping through my dictionary of all selected data.

In case I click another one, the previously clicked one goes back to default (width=1)

Anyways, you just have to make the line thicker when it's the selected one.